# How to create a range list in Python?

Tags: python

I want to have a table like this

```
a   b   c
0   16  .2
16  18  .4  
18  20  1   
20  22  1   
22  24  1   
24  26  1   
26  28  1   
28  30  1   
30  32  1   
32  34  1   
34  36  1   
36  38  1   
38  99  1
```

I then want to input a value and if it's in between **column a** and **b**'s value, then return **column c**'s value.

I thought of making a dataframe with range values and seeing if the value in is the range, but I also need to check float values:

```
x = [
    range(0,16),
    range(16,18),
    range(18,20),
    range(22,24),
    range(24,26),
    range(26,28),
    range(28,30),
    range(30,32),
    range(32,34),
    range(34,36),
    range(36,38),
    range(38,99),
    ]

values = [.2, .4, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

df_c = pd.DataFrame([x, values]).transpose()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to output if `val` is not between `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def c_if_between(a, b, c, val):
    if sorted([a, b, val])[1] == val:
        return c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def c_if_between(a, b, c, val):
    interval = sorted(a,b)
    if interval[0] < val < interval[1]:
        return c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
np.array(c)[(value >= np.array(a)) & (value < np.array(b))]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.